# Automating payments through paypal

Tags: magento, paypal

I am new to e-commerce development. In my marketplace application, I have three parties involved: Me, customer(end user) and vendor. The customer pays to me for a service to be done by vendor and when the vendor completes the service, I have to transfer the payment to them. So essentially the business logic is:

1. Customer pays to me through paypal/credit card/apple pay etc.
2. I ask the vendor to serve the customer.
3. When customer confirms the service, I pay the vendor's share.
4. Customer may also ask for a cancellation.

So, I thought to use braintree to collect the payment from customer, but I am not sure how to transfer the vendor's share automatically on a certain day of week? So for example, suppose on every Monday, I want my system to go through the completed services and transfer the vendor's share. Assuming each vendor has got a paypal account, can I do it through paypal? Is there a way to transfer the vendor's share from backend without asking me for the credentials or any conformation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this programmatically through REST APIs. You can do this by using [PayPal's Mass Payment system](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/payments.payouts-batch/). It's called Payouts when you are using REST APIs. I'm not sure if there is a Magento extension for it. You do have to be approved for it. Just go to your [REST Applications](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accountStatus/) and enable Payouts.